# service exception error 60 when trying to run google cloud speech transcription

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm new to all this, so please be gentle. I know basic php and have WAMP installed on my computer. All I need is a simple way to transcribe audio files. I have the google cloud shell sdk installed and used that to have composer install the required files (copied and pasted the command from google's tutorial), which it put in a vendor folder.

I then modified the php code google put on github which I'll paste below. When I try to run the php file, however, I get the following error message(s). What am I doing wrong? :(

[image]

```
<?php

# [START speech_quickstart]
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;


# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'xxxx';


# Instantiates a client
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
]);


# The name of the audio file to transcribe
$fileName = __DIR__ . '/audio/transcribe.mp3';


# The audio file's encoding and sample rate
$options = [
    'encoding' => 'LINEAR16',
    'sampleRateHertz' => 16000,
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
    'enableWordTimeOffsets' => false,
    'enableAutomaticPunctuation' => true,
    'model' => 'video',
];


# Detects speech in the audio file
$results = $speech->recognize(fopen($fileName, 'r'), $options);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo 'Transcription: ' . $result->alternatives()[0]['transcript'] . PHP_EOL;
}


# [END speech_quickstart]
return $results;
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and error message in the text of your question.

Comment: This is minimal as all of it is needed to get the error message. I don't know how you can replicate it, however, as I'm assuming the issue is in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicate cURL does not have the list of certificate authority's certificates available, so is unable to verify the integrity of the connection to Google. The steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/3645370) should resolve the issue.